# What is the status of Ebola these days? Is it a pandemic or endemic?

Tags: center-disease-control, endemic, polio, ebola

I know that the Zika Virus is still prominently featured in the headlines, and rightfully so, as well as [a Polio-like disease in Washington](http://www.cnn.com/2016/11/01/health/acute-flaccid-myelitis-afm-death/index.html), but **has Ebola reached a pandemic? Or is it just an endemic to Africa?**

Answer (score 3):

There is actually a current (updated daily) map of where each case of Ebola is at, and what status of each case is, you can check it here: http://www.liveebolamap.com/

Also, according to WHO (World-Health-Organization), Liberia had declared in June 2016 that it had reached an end of the Ebola outbreak. Additionally, Guinea had reported an end in transmission at the same time. You can read it here: http://who.int/csr/disease/ebola/top-stories-2016/en/

By all accounts, it was an **EPIDEMIC** to Western Africa (note endemic and epidemic are two different things... I believe you meant epidemic. Endemic means it's specific to a geographic region because of the environment or a race of people. Epidemic means widespread.) If you would like more specific information regarding the EPIDEMIC, read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_African_Ebola_virus_epidemic#Outlook